# MKPinAnnotationView disable selection/highlight but not lift and drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkpinannotationview

I have a MKPinAnnotationView that I would like to be able to long press and drag around but not tap and select. Sometimes the user will touch just the right way (a short touch on the pin) and the pin will become highlighted (darkens) instead of lifting and dragging. I use the drag to show a magnifying glass so its a bit disruptive when the user touches a pin and drags but nothing happens.

Is there a flag of some kind I can set that prevents the pin from being tap selected and always goes to drag?

I've tried setting the following flags:

```
annotationView.selected = YES;
annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
annotationView.highlighted = NO;
```

Which doesn't prevent the selection. I also tried flipping `.selected` to `NO`. I suppose I could override `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view` but I'm not sure what I could put in there to bypass the selection. And there is no `-(BOOL)shouldSelectAnnotationView...` function.

Comment: You may have to subclass the pin and then listen for the touch events and block touches that way.

Comment: @Tony That's what I figured I might have to do. I was hoping there'd be a simpler way.

Comment: Unfortunately its not very nice. I have looked for the same type of thing. Shall I put that as the answer for the question?

Comment: @Tony Certainly if you have a subclass example that works I'll accept it. I was hoping for something easy but if the answer is complex then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to subclass the pin. Here is the best example I could find. I can not write one as I am not at my computer.
https://github.com/j4n0/callout

Good luck.